# Запуск нескольких файлов py

Tags: python

Есть файл `1.py`,`2.py`,`3.py`. Их можно запустить через .bat, но нужно запускать через другой файл .py

Каким образом можно выполнить следующую задачу:

```
запускаем файл 1.py
запускаем файл 2.py
запускаем файл 3.py

if (если какой то файл закрылся сам из-за какой-то ошибки или чего-то еще (пользователь закрыл), то ):
   print(такой то файл закрылся)
```

Как видите, нужно открыть сразу несколько файлов и получить уведомление об закрытии любого из них, если это произойдет. Нагуглил разные способы открытия через сторонние библиотеки, но хочется конечно посмотреть как реализовать более удачно.
Открытие всех 1,2,3 py происходит в консоли, отдельно для каждого файла. То есть в основной код никакая информация из них браться не будет.

Comment: Запуск через `import` + `print` вставить в `finally` (из `try-finally`) в каждом модуле не подойдут?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я тут углубляюсь в асихронный фреймворк - так что вот

```
import asyncio
import sys

SCRIPTS = [
    'script1.py',
    'script2.py',
    'script3.py'
]

async def waiter(sc, p):
    "Функция которая вернет имя скрипта после ожидания"
    await p.wait()
    return sc, p


async def main():
    waiters  = []
    
    # Запуск
    for sc in SCRIPTS:
        p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(sys.executable, sc)
        print('Started', sc)
        waiters.append(asyncio.create_task(waiter(sc, p)))

    # Ожидание
    while waiters:
        done, waiters = await asyncio.wait(waiters, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for w in done:
            sc,p = await w
            print('Done', sc)
        
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: @lu13 там нет такой ошибки, наверное это уже вы что-то дописали) там были 2 другие опечатки - поправил

Comment: для ipython используй `await main()`  вместо `run`

Comment: create_subprocess_exec запускает отдельно - в диспечере задач видно ж. если нужно в отдельных окнах - нужно эти окна открыть

Comment: на место sys.executable (=="python3") нужно поставить терминал, например cmd.exe, (или поверщель ,или гитовский, а в линуксах линуксовый), в аргументы передать путь к питону (sys.executable) и путь к скрипту

Comment: @lu13  не, не так. винды нет под рукой, но там будет что-то вроде `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec("cmd.exe", sys.executable, sc) `